# Flutter StaggeredGridView.countBuilder scrollcontroll. I am having this error( type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

Tags: flutter, gridview, scrollcontroller

I am having problem when I used the scrollcontroller to controll the gridview. I am having the error ( type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'). But it was perfectly working before using the scrollcontroller. I don't where i need to change in order to remove this error. I also check the other issues regarding this in stackoverflow but couldn't get it. Can anyone check and tell me what can be change here in order to remove the error and show the data and also if my condition is right for loading 10 data in every scroll end.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:gridview_screoll/grid_content.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'constant.dart';

class ScrollableGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScrollableGridState createState() => _ScrollableGridState();
}

class _ScrollableGridState extends State<ScrollableGrid> {

  List data = [];
  bool isLoading = false;

  ScrollController _scrollController;
  int pageCount = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    this.fetchTopProducts();
    addItemIntoLisT(pageCount);
    _scrollController = new ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 5.0)
      ..addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset >=
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;

        if (isLoading) {
          pageCount = pageCount + 1;

          addItemIntoLisT(pageCount);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  void addItemIntoLisT(var pageCount) {
    for (int i = (pageCount * 10) - 10; i < pageCount * 10; i++) {
      fetchTopProducts();
      isLoading = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  fetchTopProducts() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    var url = base_api + "api_frontend/top_products";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        data.add(json.decode(response.body)['top_products']);
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        data = [];
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        title: Text('GridControll'),
        //backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(244, 246, 249, 1),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 88/100,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(244, 246, 249, 1),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 0.0, bottom: 2.0, right: 0.0, top: 0),
              child: getBody2(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getBody2() {
    if (isLoading || data.length == 0) {
      return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(primary)));
    }
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      controller: _scrollController,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      itemCount: data.length - 1,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  //builder: (context) => ProductDetails(item: data2[index]),
                  builder: (context) => productDetail(data[index]),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: cardItem2(data[index]));
      },
      staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is grid_content.dart:

```
import 'package:html_unescape/html_unescape.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget cardItem2(item) {
  // var img = item['thumbnail'];
  // var thumbnail = base_api+"uploads/product_thumbnails/"+img;
  var productId = item['product_id'];
  var thumbnail = item['thumbnail'];
  var unescape = new HtmlUnescape();
  var name = unescape.convert(item['name']);
  var unit = item['unit'];
  var discount = item['discount'];
  var price = item['price'];
  var discountPrice = item['discount_price'];
  return discount != '0%' ? Card(
    elevation: 6,
    shadowColor: Colors.white,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.0)),
    child: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.loose,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(9), topLeft: Radius.circular(9)),
                  child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                    placeholder: 'assets/loading_animated.gif',
                    image: thumbnail,
                    height: 110,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:6.0, right: 6.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            name,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              color: Colors.black87,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            unit,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                              color: Colors.black45,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 2,
                                child: Text(
                                  discountPrice,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16.0,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 2,
                                child: Text(
                                  price,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12.0,
                                    color: Colors.black38,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              ButtonTheme(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 6.0), //adds padding inside the button
                                materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap, //limits the touch area to the button area
                                minWidth: 0, //wraps child's width
                                height: 25,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  minWidth: 5,
                                  height: 40,
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(100, 186, 2, 1),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Colors.white,),
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                      side: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(100, 186, 2, 1),)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ) : Card(
    elevation: 6,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.0)),
    child: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.loose,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(9), topLeft: Radius.circular(9)),
                  child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                    placeholder: 'assets/loading_animated.gif',
                    image: thumbnail,
                    height: 110,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:6.0, right: 6.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            name,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              color: Colors.black87,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            unit,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                              color: Colors.black45,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Text(
                                  price,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              ButtonTheme(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 6.0),
                                materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                                minWidth: 0, //wraps child's width
                                height: 25,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  minWidth: 10,
                                  //height: 40,
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(100, 186, 2, 1),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Colors.white,),
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                      side: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(100, 186, 2, 1),)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

productDetail(item) {
  // var img = item['thumbnail'];
  // var thumbnail = base_api+"uploads/product_thumbnails/"+img;
  var productId = item['product_id'];
  var thumbnail = item['thumbnail'];
  var unescape = new HtmlUnescape();
  var name = unescape.convert(item['name']);
  var discount = item['discount'];
  var price = item['price'];
  var disPrice= item['discount_price'];
  var unit = item['unit'];

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0.1,
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      title: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
          child: Text(
            'Product Details',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 25.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.favorite,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                  placeholder: 'assets/black_circle.gif',
                  image: thumbnail,
                  height: 210,
                  width: 360,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.white38,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, right: 12, top: 4, bottom: 4),
                  child: Text(
                    unit,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Center(
                child: discount != '0%' ? Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      disPrice,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        price,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ): Text(
                  price,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Divider(),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Quantity',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45, fontSize: 15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  '1',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              //child: Text(store.activeProduct.qty.toString()),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 100.0, right: 100.0, bottom: 10.0),
              child: FlatButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(41, 193, 126, 1)),
                  ),
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(41, 193, 126, 1),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'BUY NOW',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                  }),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 100.0, right: 100.0, bottom: 10.0),
              child: FlatButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'ADD TO CART',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(41, 193, 126, 1), fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {

                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is the json file:

```
{
"top_products": [
    {
        "product_id": "63",
        "category_id": "59",
        "name": "Ice Cream",
        "price": "$9",
        "discount_price": "$8.91",
        "discount": "1%",
        "unit": "3 kg",
        "thumbnail": "http://192.168.0.105/uploads/product_thumbnails/72908baa78a2db38f678283a2e483903.jpg"
    },
    {
        "product_id": "65",
        "category_id": "47",
        "name": "Malta",
        "price": "$5",
        "discount_price": "$4.5",
        "discount": "10%",
        "unit": "1 kg",
        "thumbnail": "http://192.168.0.105/uploads/product_thumbnails/a63dcb5e4f883eb946585d287d25c397.jpg"
    },
   {},
   {},
   {},
   ...
],
"message": "Top hundred products",
"status": 200,
"validity": true
}
```

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      cardItem2 (package:gridview_screoll/grid_content.dart:7:23)
#1      _ScrollableGridState.getBody2.<anonymous closure> (package:gridview_screoll/scroll_grid.dart:130:20)
#2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:449:22)
#3      SliverVariableSizeBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/src/widgets/sliver.dart:144:38)
#4      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:140:29)
...
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: Can you add the line of code where causing error? You can find the error line in console output in your IDE/Editor from you running the app.

Comment: I have updated it please check

Comment: What contains in `package:gridview_screoll/grid_content.dart:7:23` line?

Comment: I have added that code two again check. I am not sure which line it's referring.

Answer (score 0):

itemCount: data.length - 1,

Change this to this:

> itemCount: data.length;

Comment: Initially i used that when i didn't use the Scrollcontroller. But after adding the controller to check the scroll reach the end or not i am having that error. But as you suggested i tried that too. But still the same error(type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index').